# How to save Previous location (LatLang) in shared preference and when got new Location replace to previous one

Tags: android, location, sharedpreferences

My question is simple, I want to save and get previous location (LatLang) In shared preference and when got new location from GPS it should be replace and get function should give latest/new location in android? Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this Code

```
public class SharedPreferenceData {

    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private float latitude;
    private longitude;



    public SharedPreferenceData(Context context) {
        settings=context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyDataFile",0);
        editor=settings.edit();
    }


    public void PushData(float latitude, float longitude)
    {
        this.latitude=latitude;
        this.longitude=longitude;

        editor.putFloat("lat",latitude);
        editor.putFloat("log",longitude);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public float getlatitude()
    {
    return settings.getFloat("lat",0);
    }

    public float getlongitude()
    {
    return settings.getFloat("log",0);
    }
}
```

**Then use the location listener**

```
    SharedPreferenceData data=new SharedPreferenceData(this);
    LocationListener locationListenerGPS=new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
        double longitude=location.getLongitude();
        data.PushData((float)latitude,(float)longitude);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};
```